# How to regex string that includes html

Tags: ios, regex, swift3

I have this string which is part of a larger string with multiple occurrences of "content" and "/content": I want to capture the whole string between "content ..." and "/content".

```html
<content type="xhtml">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">RATING: ★★★★<br/>
TAGS: Fiction, General, Science Fiction<br/>
SERIES: 20 SienceFiction Greats [19]<br/>
<p class="description">SUMMARY:<br/>Luna is an open colony and the regime is a harsh one....</p></div>
    </content>
```

I want to capture all between "content type="xhtml"" and "/content" 
I tried this code:

```
let regexPattern = "<content type=\"xhtml\">.*</content>"
let result:[String] = matches(for: regexPattern, in: dataString)
```

but it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern is close. You do not have any capturing groups within the regex. A capturing group is defined as any pattern between `()`. So with a little adjustment of the regex you will get a match. The updated Regex should look like this:

`let regexPattern = "<content type=\"xhtml\">(.*)<\/content>"`

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution as the .* pattern captures everything from the first occurrence of "content" to the last occurrence of "/content".

so this is my solution: get an array of "content" occurrences and an array of "/content" occurrences, from these arrays I can calculate the ranges I need from the string

```
private func getXHTMLContentFromDataString(dataString: String) -> [String] {
    var contentStringArray: [String] = []
    let startString: String = "<content type=\"xhtml\">"
    let endString: String = "</content>"
    var isFound = true
    var currentString = dataString
    while isFound == true && currentString.characters.count > 0 {
        if let contentStartRange = currentString.range(of: startString), let contentEndRange = currentString.range(of: endString) {
            isFound = true
            let contentStr: String = currentString[contentStartRange.upperBound .. < contentEndRange.lowerBound]
            contentStringArray.append(contentStr)
            currentString = currentString[contentEndRange.upperBound .. <currentString.endIndex]
        } else {

            isFound = false
        }
    }
    return contentStringArray
}
```